# Выборка моделей по разнице между ее datetime-полями

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

У меня в mySQL есть таблица schedule у которой есть поля *time_start* и *time_end* в формате *datetime*.

Необходимо в контексте Ruby on Rails получить из БД модели, у которых разница между своими полями *time_start* и *time_end* составляет >= 4 часа. Как правильно сделать такую выборку через active record? Если нельзя это сделать в интерфейсе Active record то как можно написать запрос в интерфейсе mySQL?

Comment: time_start и time_end - типа datetime? timestamp? или time?

Comment: Если соберёте решение на SQL, посмотрю, можно ли его затолкать в ActiveRecord/Arel. К сожалению, сам MySQL пользуюсь минимально но наслушался всяких гадостей о его системе типов.

Comment: Рабочий вариант предложили ниже

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/46772265/2076787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Англоязычное комьюнити подсказало такой вариант. В моем варианте выглядит как вполне рабочий:

```
Schedule.where("DATE_SUB(time_end, INTERVAL 4 HOUR) > time_start")
```

Comment: Не, это нет смысла портировать на Arel: и выглядеть будет убого (ад вроде `NamedFunction.new("DATE_SUB", [s[:time_end], "INTERVAL 4 HOUR"]).gt s[:time_start]`, и преимуществ межБДшной портируемости у получившегося кода не будет.